# JSON Path how to get specific data?

Tags: arrays, json

I have a problem with getting data from an array, please can You help.
This is a part of https://api.covid19api.com/summary

```
        {
      "Global": {
        "NewConfirmed": 118483,
        "TotalConfirmed": 7458238,
        "NewDeaths": 4838,
        "TotalDeaths": 424227,
        "NewRecovered": 79139,
        "TotalRecovered": 3454156
      },
      "Countries": [
        {
          "Country": "Afghanistan",
          "CountryCode": "AF",
          "Slug": "afghanistan",
          "NewConfirmed": 683,
          "TotalConfirmed": 22142,
          "NewDeaths": 21,
          "TotalDeaths": 405,
          "NewRecovered": 362,
          "TotalRecovered": 3013,
          "Date": "2020-06-11T15:18:30Z"
        },
        {
          "Country": "Albania",
          "CountryCode": "AL",
          "Slug": "albania",
          "NewConfirmed": 42,
          "TotalConfirmed": 1341,
          "NewDeaths": 0,
          "TotalDeaths": 34,
          "NewRecovered": 20,
          "TotalRecovered": 980,
          "Date": "2020-06-11T15:18:30Z"
        }
]
}
```

I would like to get some data eg Global NewConfirmed - how to make it - the below does not work - WHY?

```
const api_url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";

async function getCovid() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {Global['NewConfirmed']} = data;

  document.getElementById("global").textContent = Global['NewConfirmed'];

}

getCovid();
```

OK so to get the data from the specific country following Your instructions I have done (below) and its working:

```
const api_url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";

async function getCovid() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const global = data['Global'];
  const countries = data['Countries'][0];

  document.getElementById("global").textContent = global['NewConfirmed'];
  document.getElementById("afganistan").textContent = countries['NewConfirmed'];

}

getCovid();
```

Comment: I'd recommend a separate question for Afghanistan. In the case of `Global`, that's a property of the object. The Afghanistan data is in an array, so destructuring is not your best tool for getting the data. You'll instead want to use the find method of the array to find the country with the given name or country code.

Comment: I have changed it a little bit and included in the first question. Now its explained everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to destructure a `Global` variable from `data`, you just need:

```
const { Global } = data;
```

The rest should work fine.

Note that you don't need to use `[]` for identifier-compatible property access, so you can just do this on the following line:

```
document.getElementById("global").textContent = Global.NewConfirmed;
```

If you want to extract `Global.NewConfirmed` all in one destructuring command, do:

```
const { Global: { NewConfirmed } } = data;

document.getElementById("global").textContent = NewConfirmed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following, the safest:

```
const api_url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";

async function getCovid() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const global = data['Global']; <- Here

    document.getElementById("global").textContent = global['NewConfirmed']; <- Here
}

getCovid();
```

I think you can't access your data by destructuring it this way:

```
const {Global['NewConfirmed']} = data;
```

But like that, try it also:

```
const api_url = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";

async function getCovid() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const {Global} = data; <- Here
    const {NewConfirmed} = Global; <- Here

    document.getElementById("global").textContent = NewConfirmed; <- Here
}

getCovid();
```